# How to return the values of a filtered Hashmap in java?

Tags: java, oop, collections, hashmap, java-stream

So ive created this `HashMap` and have gone ahead filtered it using lambda and Stream :

```
public class engineMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarEngine engineOne = new CarEngine("A named Engine", 2000, 8, "E10");
        CarEngine engineTwo = new CarEngine("Another named Engine", 2200, 6, "E10");
        String a = "Another named Engine";
        HashMap<String, CarEngine> hmap = new HashMap();
        hmap.put(engineOne.getEngineName(), engineOne);
        hmap.put(engineTwo.getEngineName(), engineTwo);
        hmap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().getEngineName().contains(a))
                .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }

}
```

How can I improve my last line of code so that it returns the filtered Value? Right now it returns : `Another named Engine=javaapplication40.CarEngine@6ce253f1`

I also attempted this way

```
HashMap<String, CarEngine> map = new HashMap<>();
map.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(a))
        .flatMap(x -> ((Map<String, CarEngine>) x.get(a)).values().stream())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You are printing an empty line. It should be `e -> System.out.println(e)`

Comment: how many value you expect ?

Comment: @YCF_L Only One

Comment: Can you show what output you are expecting? You should probably implement `toString()` in the `CarEngine` class.

Comment: only one `CarEngine` or `EntryMap`?

Comment: @Eran it filters against String A. So in this case it would print "Another named Engine" which corosponds to engineTwo

Comment: @YCF_L  it filters against String A. So in this case it would print "Another named Engine" which corosponds to engineTwo

Comment: I think you should check out collect (to get a list of items matching your filter predicate).
If you want a pretty form of the filtered object in forEach, then you have to override toString method in CarEngine class.

Comment: You can print `e.getKey()` or `e.getValue()`, depending on what output you need.

Comment: @kolboc see my updated Question. I did attempt to using collect but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are searching for :

```
CarEngine find = hmap.values().stream()
                   .filter(e -> e.getEngineName().contains(a)) 
                   .findFirst() 
                   .orElse(null);
```